# Comparación de dos String en Python

Tags: python, string

Necesito su ayuda con este problema, tengo que comparar dos cadenas de texto, una cadena que el usuario ha de ingresar y otra que contiene una serie de caracteres especiales en Python, esta me debe decir cuántos caracteres especiales hay dentro de la cadena que el usuario ha de ingresar, eso es lo que he intentado pero sin éxito, me dan errores.

Muchas gracias de antemano

Código de lo que llevo hecho:

```
from itertools import count
import re

caracter = str("@!"#$%&/()=?¡¿'|")
cadena = str(input('Ingrese una cadena de texto:  \n'))
cont = int(0)
for i in caracter:
    for j in cadena:
        if caracter[i] == cadena[j]:
            cont = cont + 1

print(' \n La cadena tiene ', cont,' caracteres especiales')
```

También lo intenté con:

```
for i in caracter:
    if len(re.findall(caracter[i], cadena)) > 0:
        cont = cont + 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muy buenas, ya dieron una buena respuesta pero yo hice el ejercicio de otra forma

```
import collections as coll
import pandas as pd

caracter = str("""@!"#$%&/()=?¡¿'|""")
cadena = str(input('Ingrese una cadena de texto:  \n'))
#convierto la cadena en un diccionario
dicc=coll.Counter(list(cadena))
#convierto el diccionario en un dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(list(dicc.items()),columns=['caracteres', 'Numero de 
repeticiones'])
#hago un filtro utilizando isin y luego el resultado sumo las columnas 
cont=df[df["caracteres"].isin(list(caracter))].sum()

print(' \n La cadena tiene ', cont[1],' caracteres especiales')
```

Sobre todo utilice pandas y una funcion para filtrar, no sé que tan eficiente en términos de recursos sea. Suerte.

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

La razón por la que te manda errores es porque en tu `string` `caracter` tienes una doble comilla intermedia, que provoca que termine el `string` ahí y los demás caracteres no sean considerados como `string`. Debes escapar esa doble comilla utilizando la diagonal inversa `\` de esta forma `\"`, por lo tanto `caracter` quedaría así:

```
caracter = str("@!\"#$%&/()=?¡¿'|")
```

Por otra parte, en tus ciclos `for` cuando haces:

```
for i in caracter:
    for j in cadena:
```

Tanto el iterador `i` como `j` reciben letra por letra de las cadenas de caracteres `caracter` y `cadena` respectivamente, no reciven el índice de las letras ([Lectura recomendada](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Python/Ciclos/Ciclo-for)).

Lo que puedes hacer es iterar en cada una de las letras de `cadena` y revisar si esa letra existe dentro de `caracter`.

Ejemplo:

```
caracter = str("@!\"#$%&/()=?¡¿'|")
cadena = str(input('Ingrese una cadena de texto:  \n'))
cont = 0

for i in cadena:
    if i in caracter:
        cont += 1

print(' \n La cadena tiene ', cont,' caracteres especiales')
```

Por cierto, no necesitas ninguna librería para hacerlo.

**Nota:** Utilicé el [operador de asignación](https://ellibrodepython.com/operadores-asignacion) `+=`

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus respuestas, son oportunas ya había visto diccionarios pero no pensé que fuera necesario usarlo y lo del operador += ps aun no me acostumbro pues vengo de la vieja escuela

Comment: Pero no se están utilizando diccionarios en el código, a ¿Qué sección te refieres? Puse una liga a un artículo con la explicación de los operadores de asignación, creo que te va a servir.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda